# unable to catch error thrown by create async thunk in my component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

This is my thunk and it is failing as i am providing wrong credentials

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  "Auth/login",
  async ({ email, password }: LoginI, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const user = await api.post(
        "auth/login",
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      if (user.data.check) {
        return { loggedState: true, user: user.data.user };
      } else {
        setAxiosToken(user.data.token);
        saveToken(user.data.getToken);
        return user.data;
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      // handleError(error, rejectWithValue);
      rejectWithValue("Invalid email or password");
    }
  }
);
```

Below is my function that is dispatching the thunk and it will definitely trigger the catch block and it is triggering it. But the line  `console.log(error);` is throwing an error in the console stating `TypeError: payload is undefined`

```
  async function handleButtonClick() {
    try {
      setCurrentStatus(status.loading);
      const res = await dispatch(
        login({ email, password: password.value })
      ).unwrap();
      console.log(res);
      if (res.loggedState) {
        setCurrentStatus(status.askConfirmation);
        setRequestEmail(res.user.email);
      }
      // if (!res.loggedState) navigate("/");
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      setCurrentStatus(status.failed);
      setRequestError(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the error in your slice extraReducers. And then get the state using useSelector in the component.

```
const initialState = {
  user: user ? user : null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  errorMessage: "",
};
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => initialState,
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
                //set some loading message
            })
            .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                //handle success
            })
            .addCase(login.rejected, (state) => {
                //handle error
            })
    }
});
```

Comment: This is also a nice approach but i prefer upper one as it feels more cleaner and less code

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `return` statement, it should be

```js
return rejectWithValue("Invalid email or password");
```

Comment: yes i saw the documentation and figured it but it still gives TypeError: payload is undefined

Comment: OMG in place of return i used throw and it worked. Do you know why?

Comment: Pretty weired, Both return rejectWithValue and throw returnWithValue are ending in the catch block. But throw is executing as expected and return is throwing an error in console and the error is TypeError: payload is undefined

Comment: both throw and return should work there, only without anything should not work. Why one doesn't work for you I can't tell, sorry.